Space Curvature : isoperimetric inequality shift on human scale
I understood that on earth for example, the present matter induces a positive curvature of space. This curvature schifts the boundary of the isoperimetric inequality.
So if I consider a 1 meter wide flat* surface in my room, in euclidian geometry I could write :
S <= L²/4Pi
... where S is the surface inside the disk and  L the length of its boundary.
If I take curvature into account, could you give me the order of magnitude of the shift.
I expect it to be extremely small ... but how small ?
*: Flat ? ... it is no longer flat if we go Einsteinian ... so let's say as flat as possible ( embeded in a geodesic plan ... if such thing exists )

It's a bit unclear to me,- how you choose areas in both cases,- you choose areas with same perimeter $L$ on Euclidean and on spherical surface ? Or somehow differently ? Because exact areas shift (if any) depends on that.

The curvature-effected change is greatly depending on the curvature. The actual spatial curvature due to the presence of the Earth is, also, virtually nil. With atomic clocks you can measure time dilation differences at height differences of one meter but the difference is so small to be negligible unless you’re building a super-powerful interferometer.

The true diameter of the Earth is $4.4$ mm greater than from Euclidean geometry: https://www.johnstonsarchive.net/relativity/stcurve.pdf

@Agnius You're right. I should have simplified the question by just mentioning a disk.

@Safesphere SO I guess if we consider curvature as constant, by simple proportionality :  a 1 meter disk should see its diameter increased  by 4 mm / 13 000 m. The calculation of the surface of the disk from there in a Riemannian geometry context is not obvious to me ...
